# Is Shorter Twig Conditional possible?

Tags: conditional

Is there a way in Twig to make this conditional shorter so I don't use "craft.request.getSegment(2)" twice?

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(2) == "knowledge" or 
craft.request.getSegment(2) == "search" %}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [**Containment Operator**](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator) helps with this...

> It returns true if the left operand is contained in the right

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(2) in ['knowledge', 'search'] %}
```

OR

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(2) not in ['', 'sale'] %}
```

Comment: I hope you enjoyed learning from yourself. I didn't know you could do this!

Comment: When you post a question, there is an option to answer the question yourself at the bottom of the form (http://screencast.com/t/2mNCYI8og). I'm moving over my Google+ questions with answers and also posting things that I have to research/lookup so that I can find them again quickly & make the answer available to others.

Comment: I know, I'm just being "funny." Self-answers still amuse me even when they're mine, but this was a cool thing to learn.

Comment: I'm doing my part! My questions are going to be all Twig related probably since that's where I'm working most.